# Get value of submit button in custom post type

Tags: php, wp-admin, metabox

I'm trying to make a quiz plugin. Using a custom post type, I've made a meta box, that has the following form table in it.

```
<table class="form-table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label for="quiz_type">Quiz Type</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <select name="quiz_data[quiz_type]" id="quiz_type">
                        <option value="trivia">Trivia</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="personality">Personality</option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <span class="description">Choose the type of quiz.</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label for="quiz_data[questions][1][question]">Question</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="quiz_data[questions][1][question]" id="quiz_data[questions][1][question]" value="fffffff"
                        size="75">
                    <br>
                    <span class="description">What is the question.</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label for="quiz_data[questions][1][answers][1][answer]">Answer</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="quiz_data[questions][1][answers][1][answer]" id="quiz_data[questions][1][answers][1][answer]"
                        value="dfdfds" size="30">
                </td>
                <th>
                    <label for="quiz_data[questions][1][answers][1][is_correct]">Is Correct?</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="quiz_data[questions][1][answers][1][is_correct]" id="quiz_data[questions][1][answers][1][is_correct]">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <td>
                    <button class="add-answer button-secondary" id="add_new_answer" name="add_new_answer" type="submit" formmethod="post"
                        value="quiz_data[questions][1][answers][2][answer]">Add Answer</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <td>
                    <button class="add-question button-primary" name="add_new_question" type="submit" value="">Add Question</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The inputs are saved as an array to the post meta data. I can successfully save the text inputs when any button is pressed, and the values are recalled when I load the editor. What I am have having trouble with is adding a new input field, without javascript, when the appropriate buttons are pressed.

I thought that, with the above markup, $_POST['add_new_answer] would be set when I click the "Add Answer" button, but it is not.

How can get the value of that button when it is clicked using PHP?

Here's what I'm trying at the moment:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['quiz_data'] ) || isset( $_POST['add_new_answer'] )  || isset($_POST['add_new_question'] ) ) {

            if ( isset( $_POST['quiz_data'] ) ){
                $updated_quiz_data = $_POST['quiz_data'];
            }

            if ( isset( $_POST['add_new_answer'] ) ){
                $updated_quiz_data = array_merge( $updated_quiz_data, $_POST['add_new_answer'] );
            }

            if ( isset( $_POST['add-new-question'] ) ){
                $updated_quiz_data = array_merge( $updated_quiz_data, $_POST['add-new-answer'] );
            }

            // Update the post meta data with the updated quiz
            update_post_meta( $quiz_id, 'quiz_data', $updated_quiz_data );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I woke up and had a revelation, as you do...

WordPress was using Javascript to prevent the action of the submit buttons to make an ajax call instead. Turning off Javascript solved my problem.

Now I can move on to the Javascript enhancement of my own.